# Постройка графика на Qt5 как в rrdtool

Tags: qt5

Как сделать график на Qt через Charts как в rrdtool?

Я сделал что то похожее, отдаленно.

**Мой график который отрисовал через QAreaSeries**

[image: Мой график который отрисовал через QAreaSeries]

**График который предпочитаю сделать**

[image: График который предпочитаю сделать]

И дело в том, что мне нужно сделать разделение между верхней границей и нижней, по цвету, как у графика выше (там темнее не много). Но покопавшись в свойствах QAreaSeries, я не нашел метод, который мог бы менять цвет lowerseries или upperseries. Смена цвета у QLineSeries так же не помогает.